# KeyError: 'MYSQL_UNIX_SOCKET' Error while using flask_mysqldb in Flask app

Tags: python, flask, flask-mysql

**Edit 1**
I created a hosted mysql instance on digital ocean and I am getting a new error.

I get the following
`TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)`

I have a flask application I am working on and I am getting an error while using flask_mysqldb

Here is the error I am receiving

```
KeyError: 'MYSQL_UNIX_SOCKET'
```

My directory structure is

- `main.py`
- `auth.py`
- `website`

  - `templates`
  - `static`
  - `__init__.py`

In my **init**.py I have the following

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_mysqldb import MySQL

def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config['MYSQL_USER'] = 'flask'
    app.config['MYSQL_PASSWORD'] = 'mypw'
    app.config['MYSQL_HOST'] = 'localhost'
    app.config['MYSQL_DB'] = 'flask_test'
    app.config['MYSQL_CURSORCLASS'] = 'DictCursor'
    app.config['MYSQL_PORT'] = '3306'

    from views import views
    from auth import auth

    app.register_blueprint(views, url_prefix='/')
    app.register_blueprint(auth, url_prefix='/')

    return app
```

and in my auth.py I have the following as you can see I am attempting to print out the result to the console.

If I move the the code for mysql into my main.py it does work and I am able to print out the data. Its only when I attempt to use the mysql code within my auth.py that I get the error.

```
from flask import Blueprint, render_template, request, flash
from flask_mysqldb import MySQL
auth = Blueprint('auth', __name__)

@auth.route('/sign-up', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def sign_up():
    mysql = MySQL()
    cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
    cur.execute('''SELECT * FROM peeps''')
    results = cur.fetchall()
    print(results)

    return render_template("sign_up.html")
```

Answer (score 0):

because of `the app.config['MYSQL_HOST'] = 'localhost'`, you are using unix socket to connect the mysql. you could change MYSQL_HOST to `ip` address , in order to use `TCP/IP` to connect the mysql.

Comment: I changed the host to '127.0.0.1' however I get the same error also it does work if I have the code in the __init__.py file rather than the auth.py file

Comment: If the variable 'skip_name_resolve' is OFF (default value): mysqld will try to lookup '127.0.0.1' to 'localhost'. It still use socket to connect with client. for example: 
- ❯ mysql -uroot -h127.0.0.1 -P3306  -BNe "select @@skip_name_resolve"
0
- ❯ mysql -uroot  -BNe "select user()"
root@localhost
- ❯ mysql -uroot -h127.0.0.1 -P3306  -BNe "select user()"
root@localhost
When skip_name_resolve is ON
- ❯ mysql -uroot -h127.0.0.1 -P3306  -BNe "select @@skip_name_resolve"
1
- ❯ mysql -uroot -h127.0.0.1 -P3306  -BNe "select user()"
root@127.0.0.1

Answer (score 0):

I was providing a string for the port number rather than an integer